# problem in lists content in DNN work by python

Tags: python, list, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

i have three list [weights,n,org_weigths] in the code
below It is assumed that only List [n] changes, but when viewing the other lists, we find that they are changing with the same change in List [n]

````
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(len(weights[i])):
        print("the index is [",i,",",j,"]")
        n[i][j]=weights[i][j]*3
        model.set_weights(n)
        test_result = model.test_on_batch(X_test,y_test)
        print(test_result)
        n=org_weigths```


You must change one item at a time in List [n] and then fetch back the original data from List [B]
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python ,when you assign a value from parameter a to another parameter b, you need some attention whether the parameter b will change later. That change could affect parameter a, which is happening in your code. You need to check the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy in python. A deep copy will avoid this issue in your case. You can change two of your lines in the following way:

```
 n[i][j]=copy.deepcopy(weights[i][j])*3
 n=copy.deepcopy(org_weigths)
```